# "To improve 'the' independent living skills among people with visual loss, vision rehabilitation is important"

Tags: articles

> To improve 'the' independent living skills among people with visual loss, vision rehabilitation is important.

In the above sentence, can I put 'the' in front of independent, or there should not any article there. If I write "skill" as singular, is it okay with article 'an'?

Answer (score -1):

If you have identified "independent living skills" in contrast to some other kind of "living skills" or just "skills", then you might use "the" to point at that subset of skills again. That seems unlikely; in the use above, you should omit the definite article, because "independent" and "living" already specify "skills" completely.
I think the same argument applies to singular "independent living skill".